# how to determine jquery ajax return value or null

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am using `jquery` post ajax request to do something. the page `submit.php` return `json` value and sometime if fatal error occure it return nothing.

I cant determine the `ajax` return value or not. So how can this possible.

Here are the code i use:-

```
$.post( 'submitVoice.php', $('#frmVerify').serialize(), function( data ) {

   //some code

}, 'json');
```

Thanks.

Comment: check with console.log(data) in success call.

Comment: whats your error? please post it here.

Comment: ok it not reach in //some code block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `.done` and `.fail` handlers (or `.then`) in a chain after your `$.post` call:

```
$.post(...)
 .done(function(data, testStatus, jqXHR)         { /* use data here */ })
 .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) { /* error handling here */ });
```

Note that in neither case can you `return` a value to the caller.  If you need to do this, return the result of `$.post` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Instead use **ajax call which has success and error callback** as shown:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url : 'submitVoice.php' ,  
    data: $('#frmVerify').serialize() ,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType :'JSON',
    error: function() {
        alert("error"); 
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);    
    }
});
```

`$.post` is a shorthand way of using `$.ajax` for `POST` requests, so no difference.

`$.ajax` is generally better to use if you need some advanced configuration.

see reference [here.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: downvoted because the OP's `$.post` is a perfectly good function for this, when combined with `.done` and `.fail` (promise-based) handlers.  There is _absolutely no need_ to recommend `$.ajax`

Comment: @Alnitak..strange this is not the reason for downvote..even `$.post()` internally use `$.ajax()` to work and i think you better know that.

Comment: The downvote is unjustified, agreed. However, if in the event that returned data is blank, you can use a conditional `if(data){...}` in the success function to check :)

Comment: @Terry IMHO, it's justified.  He's replaced perfectly good `$.post` code with broken `$.ajax` code (see `data:`) and used pre-2011 jQuery `error` and `success` handlers when the simple addition of a `.fail` handler would likely have done the job (noting that it's unclear whether the OP's problem is error detecting, or an empty "positive" result).

Comment: @Alnitak....broken ajax request..well i don't think there is anything broken in above ajax request...

Comment: @Kartikeya I can assure you that the code as currently written above will not work.

Comment: You appear to have fixed it now - the error was the braces around the value supplied to `data:`.  They're not needed if the parameter supplied is a pre-serialised string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use error callback to know exact error.

```
$.post('wrong.html', {}, function(data) { })
.fail(function(xhr) { alert('Internal Server Error'); console.log(xhr)});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/n3q1wu15/1/)

Comment: Yep changed that to fail.